# border style not rendering correctly when toggle style in VUE

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, virtual-dom

Check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/v38zxufp/14/) below:

```js
new Vue({
 el: '#app',
  data: {
   flag: true
  },
  computed: {
   style() {
      let styleA  = {
          borderBottom: '1px solid red',
          borderRight: '1px solid red'
       };
       
      let styleB = {
         border: '1px solid green',
          borderRight: '1px solid red'
      }

      return this.flag ? styleA : styleB
     
    }
  },
  methods: {
   changeStyle() {
     this.flag = !this.flag;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <header>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </header>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div class="box" :style="style"></div>
      <button @click="changeStyle">changeStyle</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this demo, click `changeStyle` button to toggle two different styles.

Here is step:

- First, `styleA` is applied with `red borderBottom` and  `red borderRight`
- Click `changeStyle` button, `styleB` is applied, `green border` and `red borderRight` are expected but only the `green border` is shown.
- Click `changeStyle` button again, as we can see, only `red borderBottom` is shown, like `red borderRight` just disappear.
- Click again, you will never see the `red borderRight`

Is something wrong with comparing virtual node and rendering in `VUE`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really know exactly why this happens.

As you said, there's probably something wrong with the virtual DOM.

In my experience, when something is wrong with the DOM rendering in Vue, using `key` would solve the problem. In your case, it did. https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/Ld5e8azs/

Just add `key` to the div with dynamic style

```
<div class="box" :style="style" :key="style"></div>
```

`key` just needs to be any unique value that differentiates the 2 styles

Comment: Using an object as a value for the key attribute will show a warning. You should avoid using non-primitives, use string or number instead.

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug, but this issue was considered a [wontfix](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7756#issuecomment-371935437). This is due to the fact that `border` is a shorthand property.

Edit: Jacob beat me by a few secs, but yes, as was stated in the gh issue, the workaround is use `key` as a hash to force the render.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative but uglier 'hack' would be to differentiate the `borderRight` style, so `borderRight: '1px solid red'` in `styleA`, and `borderRight: '1px solid red '` (notice the whitespace at the end) in `styleB`.

It makes vue 'think' that `borderRight` has changed, and 'forces' it to apply the style (and 'skips' an optimisation step where it skips applying a style that vue thinks is already applied).

https://jsfiddle.net/px5qoaed/